# I cannot post this particular comment on SO or meta or SU

Tags: support, status-norepro, comments

I tried to post the following comment to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004183/) and got the orange box saying `An error occurred during comment submission`.

> It seems you cannot update a table from a trigger originated while updating the same table (understandably, mysql puts a lock on the table). But `ON UPDATE CASCADE` will anyway set the `parent_id` to `NULL`. So if an entry has a valid level (say 3) but its `parent_id` is null, it means that it is in fact a top level entry. Some tweaking might be required in the code - but I think you can rely on this behavior. If parent is null, it is the root no matter what the value of level is.

At first I thought it was network or proxy issue, but other test comments worked fine. When I tried to post that comment on other threads I got the same error. Then I tried to post it line by line and apparently the following line is the villain.

> But `ON UPDATE CASCADE` will anyway set the `parent_id` to `NULL`. So if an entry has a valid level (say 3) but its `parent_id` is null, it means that it is in fact a top level entry.

From what I observed, you cannot post this as a comment to any post in SO or meta or SU. Interestingly, if I misspell `UPDATE` in the `ON UPDATE..` part, I can submit it - but I can't fix it by going back and editing the comment.

Did I find a bug in SO code-base.... what's the price for that?

Update: I originally tried with backticks - just now tried again without backticks; both are not working. As you can see, others are able to post the same comment on this thread, but not me :(

If it'd help, here is the source of the AJAX request, copied from Firebug:

`comment=But+%60ON+UPDATE+CASCADE%60+will+anyway+set+the+%60parent_id%60+to+%60NULL%60.+So+if+an+entry+has+a+valid+level+(say+3)+but+its+%60parent_id%60+is+null%2C+it+means+that+it+is+in+fact+a+top+level+entry.&fkey=bbc7b45d69567d6869ffd0dbcd44e8e5`

The response tab in Firebug is empty.

Update: I guess Jeff is right about the proxy trying to protect me: I cannot post the following either:

```
ON UPDATE CASCADE set parent_id  NULL
```

But I can post

```
ON UPDATE CASCADE will anyway set the parent_id  to NULL
```

Comment: But `ON UPDATE CASCADE` will anyway set the `parent_id` to `NULL`. So if an entry has a valid level (say 3) but its `parent_id` is null, it means that it is in fact a top level entry.

Comment: It seems you cannot update a table from a trigger originated while updating the same table (understandably, mysql puts a lock on the table). But `ON UPDATE CASCADE` will anyway set the `parent_id` to `NULL`. So if an entry has a valid level (say 3) but its `parent_id` is null, it means that it is in fact a top level entry. Some tweaking might be required in the code - but I think you can rely on this behavior. If parent is null, it is the root no matter what the value of level is.

Comment: I just posted this on the SO question myself (but subsequently deleted it, I'm not going to take credit for your work). Doesn't seem to be a problem. Is it still happening on your end (maybe a temporary thing)? Would you like me to post it anyway and just credit it to your name, until this gets sorted out?

Comment: I can't still post the said comment here!!

Comment: Restarted the browser, cleared the cookies and cache and still not working :(

Comment: @ccomet there is nothing to take credit for - If you check my edit history there, you can see that I'm kinda learning mysql-syntax from him. Please post the original comment on that question if you can - you might wanna redirect the blames to me though :)

Comment: We help those who help themselves but help others by helping themselves help others. In other words, it is perfectly fine to learn things while answering someone's question. If anything, it promotes better growth in you while simultaneously being a potential to solve a problem.

Comment: @ccomet Thanks for helping me help myself while helping others help themselves :) The original issue still remains. I can't post that comment anywhere.. it doesn't make any sense at all :(

Comment: @ccomet: Thank you, now I've got that song stuck in my head...again. ;) @Amarghosh: Works also perfectly fine for me, what browser are you using?

Comment: @Bobby Firefox 3.6.3 I can post any other comment; I just can't post this particular comment. Nor can I edit some other comment to make it this one and save it. Strange!

Comment: @Amarghosh: Can you send this comment to f.e. a pastebin or any other website?

Comment: @Bobby: yes, he just did. He posted it here! He's only experiencing the problem when posting a comment.

Comment: @Kop: How the heck did I miss that? oO'

Comment: ON UPDATE CASCADE will anyway set the parent_id  to NULL

Comment: ON UPDATE CASCADE set parent_id  NULL

Comment: It seems you cannot update a table from a trigger originated while updating the same table (understandably, mysql puts a lock on the table). But `ON UPDATE CASCADE` will anyway set the `parent_id` to `NULL`. So if an entry has a valid level (say 3) but its `parent_id` is null, it means that it is in fact a top level entry. Some tweaking might be required in the code - but I think you can rely on this behavior. If parent is null, it is the root no matter what the value of level is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a proxy trying to "protect" you from SQL Injection.

Poorly.

Comment: It seems you're right - I've updated the question. I'll try from outside (I am currently behind office proxy) and post the results.

Comment: Just tried from outside - it is the proxy. But I thought proxies filter only incoming traffic :(